# Почему возникает SAXParseException при попытке вызвать React скрипт?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

При попытке вернуть страницу при помощи Spring Boot возникает `SAXParseException`. Причем без этого куска js кода все работало нормально. И скрипт отдельно работает нормально. Помогите пожалуйста это исправить.

Почему то проблема возникает с элементом `div`

Это Exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute
>   "id" associated with an  element type  "div".

Вот это сам HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>

    <div id="container_1"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        const user = {
            id : 5,
            age: 33,
            firstName: 'Tom',
            lastName: 'Johns',
            getFullName: function(){
                return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
            }
        };
        ReactDOM.render(
                <div id={user.id}>
                    <p>Id: {user.id}</p>
                    <p>Полное имя: {user.getFullName()}</p>
                    <p>Возраст: {user.age}</p>
                    <p>Время генерации данных: {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
                </div>,
            document.getElementById("container_1")
        )
    </script>
</body>
```

Сам контроллер на всякий случай, но до добавления js части он работал правильно:

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {
    @GetMapping("")
    public String getIndex() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Я в первый раз сталкиваюсь с react так что возможно проблема связана с отсуствием `package.json` хотя если я правильно понял он относится к конфигурациям сервера.

Но на всякий случай структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Полный текст ошибки:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute
>   "id" associated with an  element type  "div".     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1465)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:853)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1542)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1314)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2781)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_101]   at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.doParse(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:209)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:134)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:116)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]

Comment: Я не специалист в этом вопросе, но ошибка намекает на то, что ожидается открывающая кавычка в аттрибуте id элемента div. Вы не пробовали сделать что-то вроде <div id={"'" + user.id + "'"}> ?

Comment: @Роман Данилов а `id` пользователя и `id` контейнера не как не соотносятся. По идее `getElementById("container_1")` указывает на то что на странице есть элемент DOM в который сгенерированный реактом html нужно поместить. И `<div id="container_1">` как раз для этого и предназначен, и `user.id` к этому не должен иметь отношения.

Comment: А можете эксепшн залить? Может натолкнет на мысль

Comment: @Роман Данилов обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть ощущение, что Thymeleaf не нравится что-то, что вы используете в реакте. Попробуйте вынести код реакта (тело `<script type="text/babel"></script>`) в отдельный js файл, а на странице index.html подключить этот js